# Finding the index of the nonzero minimum value in R

Tags: r, arrays, list, math

```
bado<-c(0,2,1,2,3,4,1,0,0,2)
bado
which.min(bado[bado>0])
```

Hi, I want to find the index of the nonzero minimum value. I tried which.min function but which.min disregards the index of the zeros when counting indexes. In my code. min output should be 3 but it gives 2 as an output. How can I solve this? What should I use to find the real index?

Comment: if you want all minimums you can use `which(bado == min(bado[bado != 0]))`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
inds <- bado>0
seq_along(bado)[inds][which.min(bado[inds])]
```

where

- `seq_along(bado)[inds]` gives the indices of non-zero values
- `which.min(bado[inds])` gives the index of minimum non-zero value

Answer (score 2):

An option is to `replace` the values that are less than or equal to 0 to a higher value and then use `which.min`

```
which.min(replace(bado, bado <=0, max(bado) + 1))
#[1] 3
```

---

Or replace it to `NA` and then wrap with `which.min`

```
which.min(replace(bado, bado <= 0, NA))
#[1] 3
```

NOTE: The `replace` is not changing the original object `bado`

---

Or a slightly more compact option is

```
which.min(NA^(bado <= 0) * bado)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: I will use this method in another function, and amount of zeros will be change. I gave example to illustrate my problem

Comment: Replacing is not an option for me because I am also changing values of the data in my function

Comment: @BahadirAyan it is not changing the original object here.  It is just a transient replacement.  You can check the `bado` object

Comment: @BahadirAyan it is not clear when you say the amount of zeros will change.  It doesn't have any impact on the `which.min` as I am only considering the values that are greater than 0 in `which.min`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
which.max(bado == min(bado[bado>0]))
#[1] 3
```

`min(bado[bado>0])` will return the minimum value greater than 0. We compare this value with `bado` (`bado == min(bado[bado>0])`) and return the first index where the value occurs.